# How does a constructor create and initialize member variables?

Tags: c++, constructor, initializer-list

Consider the following class with member initializer list:

```
class A {
public:
    A() : a {b} {
       // do something
    }
private:
    int a {1};
    int b {2};
};
```

The compiler issues a warning that `b` is used uninitialized in the member initalizer list. This would mean, the member `b` has been already created but not initialized yet?

Thus, can we assume the following order of execution?

1. call constructor A()
2. int a; (create memory for a)
3. int b; (create memory for b)
4. a = b; (compiler warning)
5. b = 2; (assign default 2 to b)
6. execute constructor's block

This would mean, we actually do not initialize but assign values in step 4 and 5?

EDIT:
If so, what is the advantage of an initializer list, when assignments can also be done in the block after the members have been created prior entering the block?

Comment: The compiler is correct.  You can't use `b` before it is initialized.  Your assumption of the order of execution looks correct to me.

Comment: Thank you. I added a follow-up question, because I thought I got something wrong.

Comment: The initializer list doesn't assign values; it initializes objects. Sometimes that initialization involves a simple assignment, and there isn't any significant difference between initializing in the initializer list and assigning in the constructor body. But for a type with a non-trivial default constructor, assigning in the constructor body means default constructing in the initializer list, then writing over the default value with the assignment in the constructor body. If the type doesn't have a default constructor, the initializer list can't default construct it, and you'll get an error.

Comment: For a primitive like `int`, not much of a difference.  For a complex object like `sql_database` could be a lot of work to default initialize just to toss all that away and gin up a new one in the constructor body.

Comment: Well, no, the order of execution is not correct.  Memory is first obtained for an entire object (which includes sufficient provision for all its non-static members). If there is no inheritance, initialisation of the object then works by initialising each member (in the order they appear in the class definition) as specified in the constructor's initialiser list (or default-initialisaton for those members not explicitly specified in the initialiser list) and then executes the constructor's block.  If there are base classes, each base class (recursively) is initialised before the members.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence you describe is not completely correct. The sequence goes basically as follows:

1. The memory for the object is allocated; (e.g. using [`operator new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new)) Note that the memory is not allocated separately. The memory for the object is continuous, possibly with padding in between `a` and `b`.
2. Initializations of members are done where initializers are provided in the initializer list of the constructor or directly at the member declaration. in this case `a` is declared first then `b` which is why `b` has not been initialized at the time you try to read it to initialize `a`.
3. The constructor body is executed.

Note that the fields are initialized, not assigned which in case of `int`s doesn't make a difference, but if the member types would provide assignment operators and constructors there would be a difference between the 2; if you use the initializer list or initialize the member variable when declaring it the constructor is always used.